# QuickStarts source code PRISM

Tags: prism

Is it possible to find this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921174%28v=pandp.40%29 **source code** ? there is written about QuickStarts\UIComposition \UICompositionQuickstart.sln, but I really do not have idea where to find it.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available in [Prism 4.1 source](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/55576) which also includes samples and quickstarts.